# How to shut down subprocess.Popen when there is a error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to use subprocess.Popen to run `a_excution`, since `a_excution` takes several minutes, I choose Popen rather than call.

```
  p = subprocess.Popen(['./a_excution', 'input_file'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  err = p.communicate()[1]
  p.wait()
```

But the problem is that sometimes `input_file` is miss, so `a_excution` can't work. I want python script skip this error and keep going, but the script just stay here, neither error nor continue.

How can I solve this problem? If there is a error in running Popen, just skip it.

Comment: `p.communicate` will wait for the process to finish so the `p.wait` is redundant. What is the behavior of `a_excution` when the input file doesn't exist, it just hangs?

Comment: @RyanHaining If I run `a_excution` in shell, if the input file doesn't exist, it will report an error and shout down.

Comment: As long as `a_excution` exits at all, this should be fine, unless the error message it prints is enormous and is filling the stderr pipe.  What happens if you try running it without grabbing the output as in `p = subprocess.Popen(['./a_excution', 'input_file']); p.wait()`